# Flutter FirebaseAuthException 'configuration-not-found' after switching Firebase projects

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I've needed to switch Firebase projects for my Flutter web app. Authentication was working before the switch, but I can't authenticate after switching projects. I now get a `FirebaseAuthException` with error code `configuration-not-found`:

[image]

I've enabled email/password auth in the new Firebase project.
**Update:** Turns out this was enabled on the wrong (but similarly named) Firebase project.

[image]

I've run `flutterfire configure` a few times, and got my updated `firebase_options.dart` details, which seem to all point to the new Firebase project, although I'm not 100% sure what parts of those options tie back to anything in the Firebase web UI, so I'm not certain about this part.

I've also tried `flutter clean` and a rebuild, but no luck.

I had wondered if there was some old config lurking around somewhere, but if I try login with a user from the old Firebase project, it still complains about `configuration-not-found`.

What can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please double check:

- if the **`google-services.json`** pointing to your new Firebase project
- if the secrets in `firebase_options.dart` target the correct Firebase project
- Make sure you are calling this line in your main function

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

Comment: Ah you're right. I had updated `firebase_options.dart`, but it was to the wrong, but similarly named project. The Email/Password auth had not been enabled on the correct Firebase project.